# Finding a model in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm completely new to ember js. I've downloaded the last rc 2 version of ember, ember-data.js 12 revision, and looked at the manual and copy-past this code in order to be able to see the GET request to my server:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
... some resources...
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12 // Default is the REST Adapter 
});

App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),
    birthday: DS.attr('date'),

    fullName: function() {
            return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
    }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});

var person = App.Person.find(1);
```

And I get the next error:

> Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your application does not have a
>   'Store' property defined. Attempts to call 'find' on model classes
>   will fail. Please provide one as with 'YourAppName.Store =
>   DS.Store.extend()'

But as I understand I defined the Store property. Maybe I missed something because I havent read the whole manual, but honestly I can't see what's wrong. As I get it after this code I'll see get `/post/1/` request to my server, and it should be an amazing thing, but I'm still struggling with this error

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but I believe you can only call `find` from within another class. This will also fail with the `FixtureAdapter` or any other adapter.

Comment: Actually, this happens because the [app hasn't been initialized yet](https://twitter.com/tomdale/status/319545805176455169).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because ember applications are initialized asynchronously. In general you just define classes when js is being loaded, executable code belongs in hooks/callbacks. Mostly you will be using model find() from the model hook on your routes, but if you really need to do something like this right away you can do this:

```
App.then(function() {
  console.log('App has been initialized...');
  var person = App.Person.find(1);
});
```

If you want to experiment with this approach try [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgrassotti/A7N8n/) which demonstrates using `App.then()` with the ember-data fixture adapter *based on the [getting started screencast](http://emberjs.com/guides/)*